# Azure ARM template is missing siteconfig

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-appservice

Yesterday we notices that the arm-template that we are using to create a new app service slot was not able to copy settings from prod-slot to staging-slot. Api version "2016-08-01".

To copy the settings we use a script for type: "Microsoft.Web/sites"

```
"siteConfig": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('cdWebAppNameTidy')), variables('webApiVersion')).siteConfig]"
```

I also notice that when I export a template for the prod app-service, siteConfig is empty. Though, the settings are visible in another section "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"...

Anybody know if something thas changed in the api or what is going on?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Not that I've seen, the staging-slot is created without the properties from production-slot. For instance the platform is 32 bit instead of 64 bit. I'm waiting for a response from Azure support.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: The issue has been escalated to App service team. Though I've been able to get pass the issue by simply removing the whole siteConfig reference. It seems that the settings for the new staging slot are copied from the prod-slot as default nowdays.

Comment: You can add an answer here. :)

Comment: Yes, when I get feedback from Azure support.

Comment: I also am interested in how to set 64 bit on ARM template

Answer (score 0):

Microft support are still investigating this issue but it seem that a way to solve this issue is to simply remove the "siteConfig" node since the settings from production slot are copied by default.

I'm still waiting for feedback why the reference above is not working and why this was changed in azure.