# JSON validation failed:Expression must be of type 'object'

Tags: azure-web-app-service, resharper, blazor-server-side, xaf

When I go to publish my Xaf Blazor app to Azure app service in VS2022 I notice a json error according to Resharper 2021.3.1.

[image: screen capture]

The app does in fact publish.

How do I go about troubleshooting the error?

Currently I am hovering the mouse over each section to look for  hints.

[image: hint]

I tried deleting the siteConfig section but the error remains.

> JetBrains ReSharper 2021.3.1 Build 213.0.20211208.204613 built on
> 2021-12-08 ReSharper 2021.3.20211209.163805 dotMemory
> 2021.3.20211208.220240
>
> Visual Studio Professional 2022 (Version 17.0.32014.148, InstanceId
> aebef8a1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61791656/azure-arm-template-is-missing-siteconfig